# What is `1+ return` called?

Tags: portfolio

Assuming day 1 my wealth is 1. At day 2 I earned 20%. So the rate of return is 0.2 and the wealth at day 2 is 1.2. At day 3 I earned 50 % again. So the wealth at day 3 is 1.8. I wonder what is the value of 1, 1.2, 1.5 for each is called in academic?

Comment: It's called 'Gross return' (a.k.a. 'Gross Rate of Return')

Comment: In Finance it is always called Gross Return, in Statistics it is called a 'link relative' or 'chain relative' (because it links together (via multiplication) adjacent terms of the CPI index for ex.) and you may occasionally see this term also.

Comment: @rbm, AlexC could one of you post it as an answer? It's not a great question but it can't hurt to have it properly answered

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called 'Gross return' (a.k.a. 'Gross Rate of Return'). See [Zivot Course Notes](https://faculty.washington.edu/ezivot/econ424/returnCalculations.pdf) Eqn. 1.8

Also, as pointed by Alex C:

> ... in Statistics it is called a '[link relative](https://stats.oecd.org/glossary/detail.asp?ID=3907)' or 'chain relative' (because
>   it links together (via multiplication) adjacent terms of the CPI index
>   or other time series)